# Как выбрать первые два абзаца?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть такой код

```
<p class="definition marked">оооо</p>
<p class="marked">ффффф</p>
<p>142412</p>
```

Мне нужно с помощью jquery выбрать первые два абзаца (т.е. те у которых есть класс marked).  Как это сделать?

Comment: это же основы! гуглите!

Comment: хиреют новички... (первое слово написано без ошибки :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jquery selectors class](http://jquery-docs.ru/Selectors/class/#class)

Comment: нашел более элегантное
$("p").not(".marked")

Comment: >выбрать первые два абзаца (т.е. те у которых **есть** класс marked)

ну да, действительно

    $("p").not(".marked")

именно их и выберит

Answer (score 1):

Элегантнее некуда

```
$("p .marked")
```